# Json-glib serialize a boolean with value false when using gobject_serialize

Tags: vala

I'm trying to serialize the class below:

```
public class Person : GLib.Object {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public bool alive { get; set; }

    public Person (string name, int age, bool alive = true) {
        Object (
            name: name,
            age: age,
            alive: alive
        );
    }
}

public int main () {
    var person = new Person ("mike", 33, false);
    var node = Json.gobject_serialize (person);

    string obj = Json.to_string (node, true);
    print (obj+"\n");

    return 0;
}
```

While i expect the output be...

```
{
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 32,
    "alive": false
}
```

I'm getting...

```
{
  "name": "mike",
  "age": 32
}
```

How do i get the Boolean serialized even if the value is false?

Comment: It does work with `var person = new Person ("mike", 33, true);` so the problem seems to be with using a boolean with a value of false, I've not investigated further where the bug could be

Comment: Looks like this was discussed at [json-glib Issue 47](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/json-glib/-/issues/47)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default serialization function of json-glib doesn't serialize a property if it contains its default value. For boolean properties, this is `false`, unless explicitly specified otherwise.

To make sure that serialization does happen in this case, you should explicitly implement the [`Serializable.serialize_property()`](https://valadoc.org/json-glib-1.0/Json.Serializable.serialize_property.html) method yourself.